# Send email to admin with post author

Tags: posts, admin, author, wp-mail

I'm using the following to send an email to the admin when a post is publish by an  author:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'send_admin_email'); function send_admin_email($post_id){
    $to = 'admin@email.here';
    $subject = 'subject';
    $message = "Here is :".get_permalink($post_id);
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message );
```

I would like to add the post author in `$message`.

I try `get_the_author();` and `the_author();` but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Missing **global** ?

```
global $post;
```

No global variable available if you are using publish_post action hook!

Ref : http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-post-id-publishpost-action-hook-wordpress/

**Update 2 :**

or try this

```
$author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
```

So you can use `$author` where you will :D

Comment: Like that ? : `add_action('publish_post', 'send_admin_email'); function send_admin_email($post_id){global $post;
    $to = 'admin@email.here';
    $subject = 'subject';
    $message = "The author is :".get_the_author();
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message );`

Comment: I'm french so i don't understand your Ref very well. Sorry. :s

Comment: I forgot to say, my code work perfectly but i want to "add" the author in the mail.

Comment: Edited, check it out my answer @Cat

Comment: I try this `add_action('publish_post', 'send_admin_email');
function send_admin_email($post_id){
    $to = 'adress@email.fr';
    $subject = "Un nouveau contrat SMP-PRO a été enregistré par".get_userdata($post->post_author);
    $message = "Sandra, le dossier ".get_the_title($post_id)." est visible sur cette page : ".get_edit_post_link( $id, $context );
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message );
}` but it's not working… :(